# All shortest paths in networkx subject to routing criteria

Tags: python, networkx, graph-databases

I have a weighted undirected graph (~90 nodes, ~120 edges) in which I want to find the shortest path between all combinations of a subset of nodes, stored as list 'endPoints'. The shortest paths are subject to a few criteria:

1. For each combination of (s)ource and (d)estination nodes in endPoints there is a different set of intermediary nodes in the graph that I require the shortest path to **include**.
2. For each combination of s and d there is a different set of intermediary nodes that I require the shortest path to **exclude**.
3. For each combination of s and d any other node in the graph not specified in either 1) or 2) can optionally be traversed.

*e.g. For a graph containing nodes A-E I want to find the shortest paths between AB, AC, AD, AE, BC, BD, BE, CD, CE, DE. For AE the path must go via B and C but must not pass through D;  For BD the path must go via A, must not go via C, can optionally go via E, etc.*

I think the approach to use is to find all simple paths in the graph between each s and d, then to iterate over them excluding those that do not meet criteria 1) and 2) and then to find the shortest path for each remaining s and d combination using nx.shortest_path.

Finding all simple paths returns generator objects for each s-d pair and I'm not sure how to iterate over these s,d generators to apply criteria 1) and 2)

Can anyone help with next steps (or suggest an alternative approach) please?

```
from itertools import combinations

allPaths = []
for s, d in combinations(endPoints, 2):
    allPaths.append((s, d, nx.all_simple_paths(G, s, d, cutoff=999)))

allPaths
```

returns

```
[('ep01',
  'ep02',
  <generator object _all_simple_paths_graph at 0x0000025656C91BC8>),
 ('ep01',
  'ep03',
  <generator object _all_simple_paths_graph at 0x0000025656C91C48>),
 etc.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
import networkx as nx
from itertools import combinations

def check_criteria(path, include, exclude):
    path_set = set(path)
    return include <= path_set and exclude.isdisjoint(path_set)

min_paths = {}
for s, d in combinations(end_points, 2):
    min_len = None
    paths = []
    for path in nx.all_simple_paths(G, s, d):
        if check_criteria(path, includes[s, d], excludes[s, d]):
            path_len = nx.path_weight(G, path, "weight")
            if min_len is None:
                min_len = path_len
            if path_len == min_len:
                paths.append(path)
            elif path_len < min_len:
                paths = [path]
                min_len = path_len
    min_paths[s, d] = paths
```

**EDIT**:
If you want to to collect the length of the paths too, then you could pack both, path and length, into a tuple:

```
            ...
            if path_len == min_len:
                paths.append((path, path_len))
            elif path_len < min_len:
                paths = [(path, path_len)]
            ...
```

Assumptions:

- The required "inclusions"/"exclusions" are stored in dictionaries called `includes`/`excludes`.
- The path length is the sum of the edge weights (edge attribute `"weight"`) and can therefore be calculated by `nx.path_weight`. If that's not the case then adjust accordingly (e.g. by replacing `nx.path_weight(...)` with `len(path)` etc.).

The following example will hopefully illustrate that:

```
import networkx as nx
from itertools import combinations
from random import seed, random, sample, randint

seed(12345)
n = 20
G = nx.gnp_random_graph(n, 0.2, seed=12345)
for edge in G.edges:
    G.edges[edge]["weight"] = random()
end_points = [0, 1, 2]
combos = list(combinations(end_points, 2))
nodes = set(G.nodes)
includes = {
    c: set(sample(nodes - set(c), randint(1, 3))) for c in combos
}
excludes = {
    c: set(sample(nodes - includes[c].union(c), randint(1, 3))) for c in combos
}
```

```
includes = {(0, 1): {10}, (0, 2): {18, 6, 15}, (1, 2): {7}}
excludes = {(0, 1): {2, 6}, (0, 2): {8}, (1, 2): {8, 9, 13}}
```

Result is

```
{(0, 1): [[0, 9, 11, 10, 7, 4, 1]],
 (0, 2): [[0, 6, 15, 1, 4, 18, 2]],
 (1, 2): [[1, 4, 7, 5, 11, 18, 2]]}
```

or with length

```
{(0, 1): [([0, 9, 11, 10, 7, 4, 1], 2.062744452478362)],
 (0, 2): [([0, 6, 15, 1, 4, 18, 2], 1.2822628572757941)],
 (1, 2): [([1, 4, 7, 5, 11, 18, 2], 1.2624381263403164)]}
```

Comment: Thank you @Timus, this is great, although I'm running into a couple of issues implementing it on my data - 1) `return include <= path_set and exclude.isdisjoint(path_set)` is resulting in `TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'set'` and 2) path length should indeed be based on the edge `"weight"` attribute, but I receive an AttributeError `module 'networkx' has no attribute 'path_weight'` - any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @user1608180 Thanks for the feedback! Re 1) How do you structure your _inclusion_ data? In the example I have set up `includes[s, d]` and `excludes[s, d]` to be sets. It seems you haven't. So either change your data setup or change the `check_criteria` function to cast `include`/`exclude` to sets (for example by `path_set, include, exclude = set(path), set(include), set(exclude)`).

Comment: @user1608180 Re 2) See my edit. Works fine for me with Python 3.8 and NetworkX version 2.5. I have added an alternative. Let me know if you encounter further problems.

Comment: Thanks again. Re 2) I updated to the latest version of NetworkX, all now seems fine.

Comment: .@Timus Re 1) After much trawling of my inclusion and exclusion data I found an error, this too is now working as expected. However, if I leave any `includes` keys blank, e.g. for a,b in `includes = {('a', 'b'): {''}, ('a', 'c'): {'b', 'd'}}` - because there is no _requirement_ to traverse any particular node between a and b (all nodes are _available_ so long as they're not in the corresponding `('a', 'b')` entry in `excludes`) then the relevant `min_path` is also returned blank: `('a', 'b'): []` - how can I fix this and also show the path lengths for all the `min_paths`? Thx

Comment: @user1608180 Could you try `{('a', 'b'): set(), ...}` instead of `{('a', 'b'): {''}, ...}`? `{''}` is not an empty set since `''` is an actual string, `set()` is.

Comment: Ah, perfect, thank you! And to return the path length alongside each (or otherwise for all) min_paths? Sorry for the very novice Qs

Comment: @user1608180 No probs! One easy way would be to collect path and length in a tuple, see the last edit. But you could use any other structure you're comfortable with (e.g., a dictionary, namedtuple, etc.).

Comment: Fantastic, thank you